# How to pull messages in an orderly way and not randomly in a syslog script?

Tags: python

I want that log data must be displayed as in file order.
I have a python  script that randomly pulls messages from a user-defined file to provide a variety of log dataI so  want to keep the script but I want that pulls message in an orderly and not random way of a defined file (I want the log data to be displayed as in the order of the file)

```
import socket
import argparse
import random
import sys
import time
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler  
# syslog_level = ["info", "error", "warning", "critical"]
def raw_udp_sender(message, host, port):
    # Stubbed in or later use
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        message = bytes(message, 'UTF-8')
        send = sock.sendto(message, (host, port))
    finally:
        sock.close()
def open_sample_log(sample_log):
    try:
        with open(sample_log, 'r') as sample_log_file:
            random_logs = random.choice(list(sample_log_file))
            return random_logs
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("[+] ERROR: Please specify valid filename")
        return sys.exit()
def syslogs_sender():
    # Initalize SysLogHandler
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    syslog = SysLogHandler(address=(args.host, args.port))
    logger.addHandler(syslog)
    for message in range(1, args.count+1):
        # Randomize some fields
        # random_level = random.choice(syslog_level)
        message = open_sample_log(args.file)
        format = logging.Formatter\
                (' %(message)s'\
                .format())
        syslog.setFormatter(format)
        print(message)
        # getattr(logger, random_level)(message)
    logger.removeHandler(syslog)
    syslog.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--host", required=True,
                        help="Remote host to send messages")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, required=True,
                        help="Remote port to send messages")
    parser.add_argument("--file", required=True, 
                        help="Read messages from file")
    parser.add_argument("--count", type=int, required=True,
                        help="Number of messages to send")
    parser.add_argument("--sleep", type=float, help="Use with count flag to \
                        send X messages every X seconds, sleep being seconds")
    args = parser.parse_args()  
    if args.sleep:
        while True  and t != 'stop':
            syslogs_sender()
            time.sleep(args.sleep)
    else:
        syslogs_sender()
```

Comment: Can you post an example input with your expected output?

Comment: Perhaps stratify the number of log messages into m chunks and then randomly sampling a message from each chunk m could do this for you, providing you know how many messages there are. This assumes the log file is also sorted in the required order.

Comment: example input : file which contains access.log for an apache serve  (like ::1 - - [12/Jun/2020:23:31:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1062 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36") so i want that output  are logged in a file as the same order in the access.log (keep the same order of lines as the access.log file when generate logs ). knowing that the script runs on the command line and generates the output in a file but randomly (I think it's the open_sample_log function that needs to be changed) but i don't know how

Comment: @eNc can you give me an example or more explain your idea please ?

Comment: @mghban Lets say you know there are N messages in order in the log file. Then divide into 10 blocks containing N/10 messages in each block. Generate a uniform random number from 0 - N/10 and then sample that message # in the log file. Next, select from N/10 to 2N/10 and so on until you reach 9N/10 to N. Now you have 10 log messages which are in timestamp order, and you've 'stratified' your messages into 10 blocks of time, and selected via uniform random. You could also alter this to sample using other distributions alternatively random sampling the whole list and sorting is simpler and easier.

Comment: @eNc  the number of messages in the log file (input access.log)  is variable and changes in real time.

Comment: @mghban If your sample is large enough it will represent the population, this is why we sample, because the practical implications of drawing data-based conclusions from every point in population are generally not feasible. So you can take N messages at any point in time and proceed accordingly with random sampling.

Comment: Any other suggestions please ?